# PayPal IPN: (PHP) Send custom field without <form>

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using CodeIgniter to create a page where users can register for a charity cycle my club is organising.

The registration page accepts info such as name/dob/phone number etc etc, and asks the user if they want to pay online or on the day. Clicking the submit button sends the info to the same page, runs form validation, inserts the info to the database (including timestamp) and checks if the user selected to pay online. If so, the user is redirected to the PayPal donate button ***URL*** to complete their payment.

My question is, how do I send the PayPal custom field through the URL? I have tried appending &custom=whatever to the button URL, (where 'whatever' is the new database row ID and the timestamp) but this doesn't work after completing a donation with a sandbox account.

IPN:

```
public function ipn()
{
    // STEP 1: Read POST data

    // reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
    // issues with array data in POST
    // reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 
    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
    $myPost = array();
    foreach($raw_post_array as $keyval) 
    {
        $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
        if(count($keyval) == 2)
        {
            $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
        }
    }

    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) 
    {
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    } 
    foreach($myPost as $key => $value) 
    {        
        if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) 
        { 
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
        } 
        else 
        {
            $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }


    // STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

    $ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

    // In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
    // please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
    // of the certificate as shown below.
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
    if(!($res = curl_exec($ch))) 
    {
        // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
        curl_close($ch);
        exit;
    }
    curl_close($ch);


    // STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly    

    if(strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) 
    {
        // PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED! 
        $custom = explode('_', $_POST['custom']);
        $reg_id = $custom[0];
        $date_registered = $custom[1];

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT date_registered FROM registrations WHERE id=' . $reg_id);
        $array = $query->result_array();
        if($array['date_registered'] == $date_registered)
        {
            $data = array(
                'has_payed' => 1
            );
            $this->db->where('id', $reg_id);
            $this->db->update('registrations', $data);      
        }           
    }  
    elseif(strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0) 
    {  
        // do whatever
    }           
}
```

Note that I need this to work to update the 'has_payed' field of the database, which requires the row ID to be sent when the registration page is submitted.

Registration controller:

```
// check payment online
if($this->input->post('pay_online') == 1) 
{
    // redirect to paypal depending on route
    switch($route)
    {
        case '80':
        case '40':
            // €20 for over 16s
            if($age >= 16)
            {
                redirect('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=H3PFP5GGN2X5J&custom=' . urlencode($reg_id . '_' . $sql['date_registered']));
            }
            // €10 for anyone under 16
            else 
            {
                redirect('a different button URL');
            }
            break;
        case '15':
            // €15 for family
            redirect('a different button URL');
            break;
    }
}
```

The above code is working, as in, I'm being redirected to the button URL when I submit the form with the appropriate values (i.e. doing the 80km or 40km route, and being over 16yo). When I complete the payment at the PayPal page, the 'has_payed' field in the database is not updated as it should be (see IPN page).

Also, note that I do obviously have IPN enabled in my sandbox seller account.

I have searched for hours for a solution to this, but cannot find anything. Maybe I'm overlooking something simple! I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

Instead of redirecting the user to the PayPal button URL, I'm now redirecting them to a HTML page with the `<form>` code on it, and a Javascript which auto-submits the form when they load the page. This is working fine, but the database field is still not updating when the user has donated.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" id="paypal_form" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="H3PFP5GGN2X5J">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="#IPN URL#" />
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo urlencode($reg_id . '_' . $sql['date_registered']); ?>">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, of course, was simple.

CSRF protection was **enabled** in config.php, which caused the IPN to not work. Disabling it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass over the variable "custom" in your button code that you send over to PayPal.  This would then be sent back to your system thru the IPN POST.  You should then be able to grab it from there and perform your actions that you need to.

Comment: If you are using a basic PayPal Website Payments Standard button, it would just be another line added to your code.  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="123456789">

Comment: I'm sorry, but you obviously didn't read my original post completely. I'm not using a form, I'm using a PHP redirect to the button URL so I can't POST form data.

Comment: You would just need to send it the same way, a post will just append it to the URL that is in the form action.  So regardless if you are using form or not, it will still get passed over appended to the URL.  It would need to look something like "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&custom=183237"

Comment: that's what I've done, but it's not working (with a sandbox account at least).

Comment: What type of PayPal button are you trying to use?  Can you provide the URL that you are sending the buyer over to with the variables and values populated.  I ran a test with mine, and I am able to successfully send this over to the PayPal payment pages, see the custom value in my transaction details in the account and also get the custom value back to my IPN script.

Comment: Code updated. You see, in a normal PayPal form, the method is POST, which means the form fields will NOT be appended to the URL. They would be appended to the URL if the method was GET.

If I set a POST value manually, for example, `$_POST['custom'] = 'whatever';` and then do a PHP header redirect, will the POST value carry over the the new page?

Comment: It should, this is similar to how I was doing, I was just doing a redirect with the values appended on to the URL.

Comment: See my update at the end of the OP. I'm using the IPN Simulator and getting a 500 Internal Server Error. I've tried using the email script mentioned in your first post here (https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/ipn/pdt/ipn-internal-server-error-500) but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: I am not sure if we are talking about the same thing.  I understand that you want to get the custom variable back to your IPN script.  I am not sure why you are using the IPN simulator, you need to pass the variable over to PayPal first and PayPal will send it back to your script.  So you would just need to redirect the buyer to the PayPal payment page with a link similar to what I mentioned above.  This will then send the custom variable back to your IPN script, and you would just parse out the data and use the custom value that is getting sent back to carry out your actions in your script.

Comment: I appreciate your patience with this. It's my first time using any PayPal stuff. I've updated my OP again with the `<form>` code, which I'm sending the custom data in. My understanding was that I can simply use `$_POST['custom']` to get this data in the IPN script?

Comment: I would have to run some tests, with using the $_POST, I was just reading the request and populating it into my array.  As for posting on the PP Dev Forums, that site has been locked down and forum support has been moved over to StackOverFlow's forums.